# Is there a way to wrap the column header in SWT Table Header?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an SWT Table where the Table header is big and the table data is a single digit. I am not able to wrap it using SWT.WRAP. Is there anyway to wrap the text or any other solution to make the column smaller ?

Comment: Does `tableColumn.setText("line1\nline2");` work for you?

Comment: @howlger At least on macOS the header area depth isn't adjusted to cope with multiple lines like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for automatically wrapping text.

Note: you can only specify the SWT.xxx flags that are documented in the Javadoc for a control. Other flags are ignored or in a few cases may cause problems. For `TableColumn` only `SWT.LEFT`, `SWT.CENTER` and `SWT.RIGHT` are supported.